# Read the first two lines of each document in a corpus in R

Tags: r, for-loop, corpus, readlines, quanteda

I am having trouble figuring out how to read the first two lines of each document in a corpus in R. The first two lines contain headlines from news articles that I want to analyze. I want to search the headlines (not the rest of each text) for the word 'abortion.'

Here is my code for creating the corpus:

```
myCorp <- corpus(readtext(file='~/R/win-library/3.3/quanteda/Abortion/1972/*'))
```

I have tried using readLines in a for loop:

```
for (mycorp in myCorp) {
titles <- readLines(mycorp, n = 2)
write.table(mycorp, "1972_text_P.txt", sep="\n\n", append=TRUE)
write.table(titles, "1972_text_P.txt", append=TRUE)
}
```

Error in readLines(mycorp, n = 2) : 'con' is not a connection

I have intentionally not created a DFM because I want to keep the 465 files as single documents in the corpus. How can I get the headlines from the article textx? Or, ideally, how would I search only the first two lines of each document for a keyword (abortion) and create a file that contains only those headlines with the keyword in them? Thanks for any and all help with this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `readLines` function needs a connection object as argument. So as the `corpus` function doesn't return a connection, you need to create a connection  to the string in the corpus in your loop.

```
myCorp <- Corpus(quanteda::data_corpus_inaugural)

for (text in myCorp$documents$texts) {
  con <- textConnection(text,)
  first_lines <- readLines(con, n = 2)
  close.connection(con)

  # Test if the word "speaker" is in the two lines
  if(any(grepl(pattern = "speaker",x = first_lines, ignore.case = T))){
    print(first_lines)
  }
}
```

Comment: Gives errors. `Corpus not found`. Despite this working `docs<- Corpus(DirSource(folder))`, docs$documents$texts is empty!

Comment: @ThejKiran, the question was using the 'corpus' function, that is on the `tm` package. So you need to use `require(tm)` to load the library.

Comment: I did `library(tm)`. `Corpus` is the function name. Not `corpus` (this is what I wanted to say in the previous comment).

Comment: What is `data_char_inaugural`?

Comment: `data_char_inaugural` is a dataset of the `quanteda` library. This name is now deprecated and you need to use `data_corpus_inaugural`.

Comment: Error in Corpus(data_corpus_inaugural) : 
  inherits(x, "Source") is not TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest two options:

#### regex substitution to keep just first 2 lines

If your first two lines contain what you need, then just extract them using a regular expression that plucks out the first two lines.  This is faster than the loop.

@rconradin's solution works but as you will note in ?corpus, we strongly discourage directly accessing a corpus object's internals (since it will change soon).  Not looping is also faster.

```
# test corpus for demonstration
testcorp <- corpus(c(
    d1 = "This is doc1, line 1.\nDoc1, Line 2.\nLine 3 of doc1.",
    d2 = "This is doc2, line 1.\nDoc2, Line 2.\nLine 3 of doc2."
))

summary(testcorp)
## Corpus consisting of 2 documents.
## 
##  Text Types Tokens Sentences
##    d1    12     17         3
##    d2    12     17         3
```

Now overwrite the texts with just the first two lines.  (This also discards the second newline, which if you wish to keep, just move it to the first capture group.)

```
texts(testcorp) <- 
    stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(texts(testcorp), "(.*\\n.*)(\\n).*", "$1")
## Corpus consisting of 2 documents.
## 
##  Text Types Tokens Sentences
##    d1    10     12         2
##    d2    10     12         2

texts(testcorp)
##                                     d1                                     d2 
## "This is doc1, line 1.\nDoc1, Line 2." "This is doc2, line 1.\nDoc2, Line 2."
```

#### using `corpus_segment()`:

Another solution would have been to use `corpus_segment()`:

```
testcorp2 <- corpus_segment(testcorp, what = "other", delimiter = "\\n", 
                            valuetype = "regex")
summary(testcorp2)
## Corpus consisting of 6 documents.
## 
##  Text Types Tokens Sentences
##  d1.1     7      7         1
##  d1.2     5      5         1
##  d1.3     5      5         1
##  d2.1     7      7         1
##  d2.2     5      5         1
##  d2.3     5      5         1

# get the serial number from each docname
docvars(testcorp2, "sentenceno") <- 
    as.integer(gsub(".*\\.(\\d+)", "\\1", docnames(testcorp2)))
summary(testcorp2)
## Corpus consisting of 6 documents.
## 
##  Text Types Tokens Sentences sentenceno
##  d1.1     7      7         1          1
##  d1.2     5      5         1          2
##  d1.3     5      5         1          3
##  d2.1     7      7         1          1
##  d2.2     5      5         1          2
##  d2.3     5      5         1          3

testcorp3 <- corpus_subset(testcorp2, sentenceno <= 2)
texts(testcorp3)
##                    d1.1                    d1.2                    d2.1                    d2.2 
## "This is doc1, line 1."         "Doc1, Line 2." "This is doc2, line 1."         "Doc2, Line 2."
```